# Wiring Genie garage controller with GoControl Z-Wave module

Tags: garage-door-opener, z-wave

## Issue

Which pins on the `Genie`'s garage controller should I  connect `Z-Wave` module's cables?

## Background

I'm installing Z-Wave bind module for Genie's garage controller. Section 7 in the Z-Wave module's manual reads:

> Connect the GD00Z-8-GC connection wires to the push-button wall console terminals on the garage door opener. The terminals may be named "PWC", "WC", "PB", "PUSHBUTTON", or "RED and WHITE". Terminal names and locations vary by model.

I opened the back of the garage controller. It looks much convoluted than the manual expects. I can't find any of those terminals.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## Components in use

- Genie's controller: [CM7600IC (geniecompany.com)](https://store.geniecompany.com/collections/by-model-pro95-cm7600-cm8600). Found a [manual online (usermanual.wiki/Genie)](https://usermanual.wiki/Genie/CM7600.2339895774/html).
- Z-Wave bind: GoControl GD00Z-8 ([installation manual (z-wavealliance.org)](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/ProductManual/File?folder=&filename=product_documents/3710/10025383%20Rev-B%20-%20GD00Z-8%20GC_WEB.pdf))

---

**UPDATE**: Resolved! As [diy.stackexchange.com#250765/51023](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/250765/51023) suggests, I didn't have to open the back cover (to expose the detailed wiring). I just had to open the front cover and wire the 2 cables to the wall-opener's (in the picture below, the white cable coming from the right and splits is the one connects to the Z-Wave module I added).
[image]

Comment: curious: when was the opener made?

Comment: after consulting the manual's wiring diagram, the terminal is shown in your first pic in the upper left. shorting the blue and either green wire should be the same as pressing the wall button. you can test with a short piece of wire or even some needle-nose pliers to touch both push-on connectors (left, 2nd to left) at once (they have no rubber booties around the connection). The two external wires of the zwave thing should connect to those. you can also connect a relay there (NO-COM) then power that relay temporarily with a smart outlet feeding a wall wort (how i rigged a friends system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming all the Z-wave module does is momentarily close the contacts to simulate someone pushing the "open/close" button.

Do you have a pushbutton control already?  If so, follow the low-voltage wires from that into the garage door opener and connect to the same terminals.  I can't really tell from those pictures where the incoming low-voltage cable(s) are located, but they are commonly terminated on screw terminals or spring terminals.  Most likely you can access them without removing the cover.